# How to properly return count(*) values from scalar valued function

Tags: c#, windows, t-sql

Every time I execute my code I get "false" from method

```
 public bool exists(int vpisna, string geslo)
    {
        bool a = false;
        Uspeh = true;


        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.fnExists(@Vpisna,@Geslo)", povezava);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vpisna", vpisna);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Geslo", geslo);

        try
        {
            povezava.Open();
          int result =(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();


            if (result==1)
            {
                a = true;     
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ex = e;
        }
        finally
        {
            povezava.Close();
        }

        return a;
    }
```

My scalar valued function:

```
[dbo].[fnExists](
    @Vpisna int,
    @Geslo nvarchar(40)
)
RETURNS INT AS BEGIN

DECLARE @a int

SET @a = (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        Student
    WHERE
        ID = @Vpisna
        AND
        Geslo = CONVERT( nvarchar(40), HashBytes('SHA1', @Geslo ), 2 )
)  

RETURN @a
END
```

Everytime I get a false result, even when I try to manipulate data inside of the scalar valued function. When I try the SELECT statement on real data without a the function it works inside the SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT @a = COUNT(*) ...` instead of `SET @a = ( SELECT COUNT(*) ...`?

Comment: The result is still false. The form where I call the method,  returns the boolean variable converted to string.

Comment: Code that silently kills exceptions won't be helping if you are, in fact, currently experiencing an exception. Get rid of the `try`/`catch` block. (And, instead, make the `SqlConnection` be local to this method and in a `using` so you don't need to manually have the `finally` either)

Comment: No exceptions are thrown thats the funny part. I have a suceess property that goes false when EX is thrown and an Ex property for the exceptions. Other methods work because the connection is always the same. I don't like <code>using</code> statements. Why are they so popular for SQL?

Comment: Is your count really coming back with just one record?  Seems to me that if your function gets a count of 2 or more, your C# will misrepresent the result... "if (result==1) {a = true;}" only produces 'true' when the count is 1.

Comment: No, I placed breakpoints but the result is 0, everytime it's just one row.

Comment: Aside:When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Comment: So in query IF EXIST SET @variable=1 ELSE.... RETURN @variable?

Comment: Typically something like `set @A = case when exists ( select 42 from Student where Id = @Vpisna and Geslo = CONVERT( nvarchar(40), HashBytes('SHA1', @Geslo ), 2 ) ) then 1 else 0 end;`. If _any_ row meets the conditions in the `where` clause then `@A` will be set to `1`, otherwise `0`. The query optimizer can take shortcuts when you don't need a precise count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code series is wrong. Before create sql command must open sql connection or must open from `sqlcommand`.
Use this;

```
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("sql-connection-string");
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select 1", cnn);
```

or

```
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("sql-connection-string");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select 1", cnn);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[dbo].[fnExists](
@Vpisna int,
@Geslo nvarchar(40)
)
RETURNS INT AS BEGIN
DECLARE @a int
SELECT
    @a = COUNT(*)
FROM
    Student
WHERE
    ID = @Vpisna
    AND
    Geslo = CONVERT( nvarchar(40), HashBytes('SHA1', @Geslo ), 2 )
RETURN @a
END
```